# Removing singleton dimension of scan capture group

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying to come up with a good way to do the following. I have a string, such as this one:

```
foo = "bar = everybody\nbar = say\nbar = hey\nbar = ho"
```

And I am scanning through it like this:

```
foo.scan(/^bar = (.*)$/)
```

That returns:

```
[["everybody"], ["say"], ["hey"], ["ho"]]
```

What I want is:

```
["everybody", "say", "hey", "ho"]
```

So basically, I would either like to remove the singleton dimension of the array or reformat the scan code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-flatten) may help

```
foo = "bar = everybody\nbar = say\nbar = hey\nbar = ho"
foo.scan(/^bar = (.*)$/).flatten
#=> ["everybody", "say", "hey", "ho"]
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks!